# How to make mobile movement using CharacterController

Tags: unity, movement, unityscript, mobile

How can i change my movement for mobile i think left and right gonna work but i don't know what should i do for jump

```
private void Update()
{

    vector = Vector3.zero;

    if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        /*verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime*/;
        verticalVelocity = -0.5f;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            verticalVelocity = jump;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    vector.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
            vector.x = speed;
        else
            vector.x = -speed;
    }
    vector.y = verticalVelocity;
    vector.z = speed;

    characterController.Move(vector * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I solved the problem this way

```
if (characterController.isGrounded)
    {

        verticalVelocity = -0.5f;

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.y > Screen.height / 2)
            {
                verticalVelocity = jump;
            }
            else
            {
                verticalVelocity = -jump;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    vector.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * speed;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if(Input.mousePosition.y < Screen.height / 2)
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.x > Screen.width / 2)
                vector.x = speed;
            else
            {
                vector.x = -speed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you want your game to be played on mobile? What have you tried so far to achieve that goal?

Comment: I fixed the problem

Comment: Want to share your solution as an answer to help others with similar issues? Or would you prefer to just delete the question if it's no longer needed?

Comment: I can share, no problem. I didn't test with a mobile device yet, but probably it's gonna work

Comment: Don't edit your solution into the question. Post it as an answer. (The "Your Answer" box on desktop, or "Add an Answer" button on the app)

Comment: You can use unity's Mobile Device Touch input.